# Line Breaks in MS Access Report

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, report, line-breaks

I am using VB.NET and MS ACCESS 2007.

I'm trying to create a header for a receipt.

In my program, I want the user to input the header for the receipt using a richtextbox.

I want to store the user's input to the database and make it a header for the receipt.

Example:

The user's input as shown in the richtextbox is:

*Juan Dela Cruz*

*16*

*Tokyo, Japan*

And when it is stored to the database, it is displayed as:

Juan Dela Cruz [there a symbol in here] 16 [symbol] Tokyo, Japan

The same will also be displayed in the MS Access Report which is what I don't want Access to show me.

I want Access to give me a result the same with the user's input in the richtextbox:

*Juan Dela Cruz*

*16*

*Tokyo, Japan*

How will I be able to do that?

The code executed once the button is clicked:

```
Try
        If receiptEdit = 0 Then
            Dim updateHeader = "UPDATE tbl_receiptdetails SET RHeader = '" & boxReceipt.Text & "'"
            ExecNonQuery(updateHeader)
            MsgBox("Receipt Header Updated")
        ElseIf receiptEdit = 1 Then
            Dim updateFooter = "UPDATE tbl_receiptdetails SET RFooter = '" & boxReceipt.Text & "'"
            ExecNonQuery(updateFooter)
            MsgBox("Receipt Footer Updated")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
```

Comment: what do you mean with symbol ? a Rectangle? do you have some japanese characters in there?

Comment: I can't paste the symbol here. It just give me newline.

Comment: Are you saying that in Access the CrLf character is being displayed as as rectangle instead of creating a carriage-return?

Comment: before saving try replacing.   `val = Replace(val, vbCr, vbNewLine)
val = Replace(val, vbLf, vbNewLine)`

Comment: Yes clweeks, I displays as a rectangle

Comment: Belial09. Example the input of the user is RichTextBox.Text. Should I do it like this: val = Replace(RichTextBox.Text, vbCr, vbNewLine) val = Replace(RichTextBox.Text, vbLf, vbNewLine)   ??

Comment: can you provide the code in your first post where you save the data to the database, i will show you then what i mean.

Comment: replace `boxReceipt.Text` with `boxReceipt.Text.Replace(vbCr, vbNewLine).Replace(vbLf, vbNewLine)`

does this work?

Comment: oh yeah. It worked.! Bear HUG!!! :D Thanks yow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@GM-XileGM-Xile:

The Solution from my comment, as answer:

replace

```
boxReceipt.Text
```

with

```
boxReceipt.Text.Replace(vbCr, vbNewLine).Replace(vbLf, vbNewLine)
```